# Excel changes based on cell contents

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to create a script that will apply to an Excel script for an SSIS package that will change column visibility based on a cell's contents.

Basically I have a column that will contain the name of a report.  This report will either contain the word "MID" or "END", which determines if it is a mid month or a month end report.  Right now, I have the script run through the contents of the cells in that column and should be making cells visible or not, but I believe the issue is that the `If Else` isn't applying before the integer I am using is increased, so it runs through the whole list looking if it is the first condition of the `If` statement, but doesn't loop back to the beginning for the `Else` statement.

If there is a better way to make changes based on a cell's contents in a range of cells, please let me know as this will be used extensively.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
'Mid Month/Month End Changes
ReportRange = .Range("B2", "B" & lastrow)
k = 0
For k = 0 To ReportRange.Rows.Count - 1
    ReportCell = .Cells(2 + k, 2)
    Report = ReportCell.Value
    MidHrsCell = ReportCell.Offset(, 5)
    EndHrsCell = ReportCell.Offset(, 6)

    For Each Cell In ReportRange
        If InStr(Report, "MID") > 0 Then
            EndHrsCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else 
            MidHrsCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have looped inside your loop to go around the same range. I have simplified it into only one loop per below.

```
'Mid Month/Month End Changes
ReportRange = .Range("B2", "B" & lastrow)
k = 0
For Each Cell In ReportRange
    Report = Cell.Value
    MidHrsCell = Cell.Offset(, 5)
    EndHrsCell = Cell.Offset(, 6)
    If InStr(Report, "MID") > 0 Then
        EndHrsCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        MidHrsCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, that does remove that extra loop, but unfortunately the results are the same.  I have tested to see that the InStr(Report, "MID") is pulling the correct value (0 for what I am testing), but the column is not hidden.

Comment: Never mind.  I am an idiot.  I had a section that was applying autofitting to the entire sheet after the hidden columns code.  Thanks for the help with the loop!